# Unexpected Mathematical Division Output - C++

Tags: c++, math, types, division

I have this segment of testing code (there is quite a lot of other material; however, it is extremely dense and likely irrelevant to this question), which has been producing some inexplicable output. When compiled, this block:

```
cout << team1[m].rating << endl;
cout << team2[n].rating << endl;
cout << team1.size() << endl;
cout << team2.size() << endl;
cout << (team2[n].rating - team1[m].rating) / team2.size() << endl;
cout << (team1[m].rating - team2[n].rating) / team1.size() << endl;
```

produces the output:

```
10 
30 
2 
2 
10 
2147483638
```

'team1' and 'team2' are both of type `vector<player>` (without backslash) and the 'player' struct appears as follows:

```
struct player {
string name;
int rating;
player(string Name, int Rating) :
    name(Name), rating(Rating) {}
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs because the `size()` function of `std::vector` returns a `size_t`, which is unsigned. When dividing an `int` (such as the rating) by a `size_t`, the `int` is promoted to an `unsigned int`.

Converting a negative number to an unsigned value will cause that value to underflow, becoming larger than the maximum positive value which can be represented by the original signed type.

In order to prevent this, you need to explicitly state that the size() arguments should be converted to `int` before the division.

```
cout << (team2[n].rating - team1[m].rating) / static_cast<int>(team2.size()) << endl;
cout << (team1[m].rating - team2[n].rating) / static_cast<int>(team1.size()) << endl;
```

Answer (score 9):

`team1.size()` and `team2.size()` are unsigned (`size_t`) - change your code to:

```
cout << (team2[n].rating - team1[m].rating) / static_cast<int>(team2.size()) << endl;
cout << (team1[m].rating - team2[n].rating) / static_cast<int>(team1.size()) << endl;
```

Comment: Why do you assume that the required result is signed? It's very possible that an absolute value is needed in the calculation

Comment: @icepack: in the absence of any information from the OP to the contrary about the expected result I can only work with the provided information - it appears that the modulo wraparound from the unsigned promotion is what is "unexpected" in this case. I'm sure the OP will clarify further if some other behaviour is required.

Answer (score 5):

`(team1[m].rating - team2[n].rating)` is equal to `-20`. This expression result is being promoted to `unsigned int` according to rules of mixed expressions and divided by `team1.size()`, yielding `2147483638` which is the `unsigned int` equivalent for `signed int` `-10`.